# Xpath: select h2 parent with no a child

Tags: xpath

I have the following html:

```
<div class="stack">
    <h2 class="overflow">
       <img src="http:..">
       text
    </h2>
    <div class="sublist">
        <table>
        ...
        </table>
    </div>

    <h2 class="overflow">
        <a href="http://...">link</a>
    </h2>
</div>
```

As you can see, the .sublist div always follows a  with  and some text, it's like the div is a sublist of the h2(the h2 is the title of the sublist). The other  contains an anchor tag.

I'd like to get all the h2 tags which preceeds the div .sublist.

This is my current xpath clause:

```
//div[@class="stack"]/h2/*[not(descendant::a)]
```

And I end up getting different elements(a, div, img) but the h2 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to get all the h2 tags which preceeds the div .sublist.

How about:

```
//div[class="sublist"]/preceding-sibling::h2
```

Comment: That's good. I had to change from h2 to h2[1] to get the inmediante preceding sibling.

Comment: @Rod0n yes, the path I gave would return _all_ the h2 tags which precede the sublist div.

Answer (score 1):

Try `preceding-sibling`:

```
//div[@class="stack"]/div[@class="sublist"]/preceeding-sibling::*
```